# Place linear function on orthonormal system

Tags: r, function, graph

I've been trying for 2-3 days to do a really simple linear function such as f(x) = ax+b and place it on a orthonormal system. I have no experience at all in R and my research have been unsuccessful.

My attempts so far (I have close to 0 experience in code overall) are:

```
fun <- function(x){ return(a x + b) } 
curve(fun, from = -100, to = 100, ylab = expression(ax+b), main = "curve function")
```

Also functions I've been trying to use:
`curve`, `abline`, `plot`.
And things I've found like

```
plot(c(0:9),c(1:10)) 
abline(2,1,col="red",lwd=2)
```

were not really helpful but at least I know I can do what I want to and other things I haven't saved. (Sorry for my english.)

Comment: Please show us what you tried first.

Comment: please add this to your question

Comment: 1) You're missing the multiply `return(a * x + b)`; 2) You do not assign values to `a` and `b`.

Comment: Ooh i got some improvements thanks to you ! So i'm left with that fun <- function(x){
  return(3*x + 11)
} 
curve(fun, from = -10, to = 10, ylab = expression(ax+b),
      main = "curve function")  The instructions i was given were simple but i kinda want to push it further now. Anyway thanks guys, i'll come back to learn more : D

Answer (score 1):

The function code is wrong, it's missing the multiplication operator.

```
fun <- function(x, a, b){ a * x + b }
```

As for the orthonormal system, graphics parameter `asp` will set the aspect ratio.

```
curve(fun(x, a = 1/3, b = -10), from = -100, to = 100, 
      ylab = expression(a * x+b), 
      asp = 1,
      main = "curve function")
```

[image]

---

### Edit

Function `abline` needs the plot to be open first. But the plot is like the one above.

```
plot(-100:100, -100:100, type = "n")
abline(-10, 1/3)
```

Comment: Oh that's even cooler ! But the abline function is used to had another line on the graph right ? But when i use it, it overwrites the previous one

Comment: @Hécate `abline(20, -1/2)` doesn't overwrite the previous one. `curve` restarts the plot unless `add = TRUE` is set but `abline` needs a previously open plot and adds lines to it.